# Getting the HTML of a DIV with another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of thumbnails. Of these I know the `link` in my JQuery script - however, I need to get the HTML from the `.caption`, and I just can't make it do that.

I've tried the following things

```
$('a.thumbnail').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.caption').html()
    $(this).find('.caption').html()
    $(this).children('.caption').html()
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{ URL::asset($item->image) }}" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="caption" align="center">
        {{ $item->name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would also work, since the `.caption` is a sibling of your `a`:

```
$('a.thumbnail').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.caption').html();
});
```

Why yours don't work:

```
$(this).closest('.caption').html() // .caption is not an ancestor of the a
$(this).find('.caption').html()  // .caption is not a descendant of the a
$(this).children('.caption').html() // .caption is not a child of the a
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('a.thumbnail').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.thumbnail').find('.caption').html();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wthDY/1/)**

When you click the image, you need to use `.closest()` to traverse up to the containing div, and the use find to go back down to `.find()` the caption.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$(this).parent().find('.caption').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".caption").text();
```

or Perhaps

```
$(".thumbnail").find(".caption").text();
```

Although these might give you the entire class. Have thought about adding ids?
I've done this before using the Razor engine:

```
 @foreach (var temp in ListOfStuffWithIds)
 {
   <tr class="class" >
       <td class="tdClass" >
          <input id="@temp.Id" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="tdClass2">@temp.Id</td>
        <td>@temp.Name</td>
    </tr>  
 }
```